# Creating webhook listener, sending email , cookies and single sign-on in angular

Tags: angular, webhooks

I had been evaluating newest and finest Java script frame works now a days (Angular & React)

I'm not here for comparison, and want to create a mini-app to understand its capability. following is what I intent to create:

**1)** Webhook listener in Angular to listen to various web hook events subscribed to other end points.

**2)** Sending email notification on various occasions. ( I know if combined with other server side language this is possible, However I'm looking for any means to do this via Angular)

**3)** Cookie maintenance to remember user and his preferences.

**4)** Single sign-on to famous social engines viz (Facebook, twitter etc.)

If any one faced above scenario and created something similar, please help.

I know Angular can be combined with other server side languages(C# , Java) to 
make an application that will achieve all of the above. I still want to find out the best possible way of implementing the same.
Even if any body know any node package that already doing any of above!

Thank you.

Comment: Angular is a client-side framework. It runs inside the browser. All your questions relate to tasks that need to be done by the server. So Angular (and React) are irrelevant.

Comment: @JBNizet, I disagree, Cookie and session management are not just server specific. However I agree on email and webhook listener activity.

Answer (score 0):

1) We can use pure javascript for session management there is session/local storage for that. For example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ token: token, name: 
name }));
```

or

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ token: token, name: 
name 
}));
```

the above code will work both in react and angular as it is not library or framework specific.

Same with cookies. Vanilla javascript can be used for the same.

2) For social sign in for Facebook, I have used a Facebook library in angular
  ng2-facebook-sdk
And for Google, you have to use the google SDK for javascript provided by Google.

And yes few of the things are only possible through server-side languages like for mail notifications.

Thanks